# Android WebView Canvas randomly not working with different Widths and Heights

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, android-webview

For the following tests I've used the following HTML snippets I've used an online HTML-editor and the Android-WebView-Tester from the Android-Emulator, with a 9.7" screen.

This Code is working well [(Image of the Android-Webview-Tester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upL0X.png):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

//canvas.setAttribute("height", "500");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

This Code is working well on Browsers, but not in the Android-Emulator [(Image of the Android-Emulator not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJPQt.png):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

//canvas.setAttribute("height", "500");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

Is this a known problem? Did I miss something? I'm using Android 8.1

I've got no problem with the Android-Chrome-Browser, but I'm building a Cordova-App with exactly the same problems. Chrome-Webinspector doesn't give any errors/warnings.

Comment: Seems like a well known issue for years now and Android Development time have not yet delivered a solution fro this.